# How to keep post variable value in other page even after refreshing page in zend framwork

Tags: php, zend-framework

I cannot figure out to keep data even after refreshing page;

**My case;**

I have form which after clicking submit direct to another action where you have to keep this data even after refreshing page; I am passing data using POST method

Is there way for to keep post data even after refreshing page in zend framework.

Comment: Sessions, databases, what have you tried?

Comment: [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//In bootstrap
Zend_Session::start();


//in post page
$request = new Zend_Session_Namespace('request');
$request->post = $_POST;

//some other xyz page visited after posting data
$request = new Zend_Session_Namespace('request');
$post = $request->post ; //noew $post is equal to wat were posted in previous request
```

Comment: I got another issue regarding this problem. For example, I am using partialLoop and I don't know how many array I do have which mean I don't know how many session should I create. Morevoer, if i pass this value to another action again I don't know how many session I have to call. Actually, this can be solve by stroring number of array you may have but this requireirs hard coding. Is there another other way, thanks